# Variável com JS / Html

Tags: javascript, html

Quem puder ajudar,

Preciso montar uma assinatura de e-mail onde o link da imagem que preciso carregar foi composta e inserido em uma variável(linkAss) JS.

Não estou conseguindo carregar a imagem dentro do HTML (Variavel do Link).

Como eu posso fazer isso?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Empresa</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,700,900,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
html, body { font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var linkAss = "https://wp.net/ImagensAss/" + %%userPrincipalName%% + ".png"
</script>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="100" style="vertical-align: top;">Variavel do Link</td>
```

Comment: que ser `%%userPrincipalName%%` ?

Comment: é uma variável do Active Directory eu pego os dados dessa variavel e componha com o restante para formar uma url da imagem gravada no meu banco de dados.

Comment: já vou testar, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente...

Answer (score 0):

É isso ?

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Empresa</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,700,900,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    html, body { font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
      var userPrincipalName = "name";
      var linkAss ="https://wp.net/ImagensAss/"+userPrincipalName+".png";
      document.getElementById('link').src = linkAss;
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="load()">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="100" style="vertical-align: top;"><img src="" id="link"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: <td width="100" style="vertical-align: top;" id="link"></td> Nesta linha onde está o id="link" ele trás a url, mas como eu faço para carregar a imagem na pagina?

Comment: nesta variável "linkAss" eu armazeno a url da imagem e mostro na id-"link", mas como eu faço para carregar ela ao invés d mostrar?

Comment: ah sim, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: pronto! Desculpe a demora.

Comment: Você é um anjo, muito obrigado!!! Me ajudou muito... :)

Comment: Marca a resposta como certa pf